# Cannot use custom spring converter in unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using simple converter for converting string to enum. Here is the custom converter:

```
@Component
public class SessionStateConverter implements Converter<String, UserSessionState> {

    @Override
    public UserSessionState convert(String source) {
        try {
            return UserSessionState.valueOf(source.toUpperCase());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.debug(String.format("Invalid UserSessionState value was provided: %s", source), e);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am using UserSessionState as `PathVariable` in my rest controller. The implementation works as expected. However when I try to unit test the rest controller it seems that conversion does not work and it does not hit the controller method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private FormattingConversionService conversionService;

@InjectMocks
private MynController controller;


@Before
public void setup() {
    conversionService.addConverter(new SessionStateConverter());
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setConversionService(conversionService).build();
}


 @Test
public void testSetLoginUserState() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/user/login"));
}
```

}

In debug mode I get following error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'rest.api.UserSessionState': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

In my opinion the mock for conversion service does not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `conversionService` is a mock.

So this:

```
conversionService.addConverter(new SessionStateConverter());
```

calls `addConverter` on mock. This does nothing useful for you.

I believe you want to use real `FormattingConversionService`: to do it you need to remove `@Mock` annotation from `conversionService` field and use a real instance of `FormattingConversionService` instead:

```
private FormattingConversionService conversionService = new FormattingConversionService();
```

---

If you need to track invocations on real objects as you would do on mock check out : [`@Spy`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Spy.html)

Answer (score 7):

If anyone uses implements `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<IN,OUT>` and if you are getting similar error while using mockMvc, please follow the below method.

```
@Autowired
  YourConverter yourConverter;

  /** Basic initialisation before unit test fires. */
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    FormattingConversionService formattingConversionService=new FormattingConversionService();
    formattingConversionService.addConverter(yourConverter); //Here

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(getController())
        .setConversionService(formattingConversionService) // Add it to mockito
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: I was suffering for two hours to make it work, your solution is just PERFECT! Thank you so much!